# Cordova/Phonegap load external site in main Cordova webview

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, webview

***What i want***

I have external web-resource that i want cordova webview to simple open and be able to navigate through its inner navigation.

***Description***

InAppBrowser docs said

> The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't
>   access Cordova APIs. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended
>   if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content, **instead of**
>   **loading that into the main Cordova webview**

So i have an trusted external links (let's say http://www.google.com i want to load in main webview and want to control its process though window.location.href or user links click.

***What i tried***

Generated hello world app with latest cordova and inserted

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'
```

to its onDeviceReady. It's config was already having (and i tried to change it to concrete adress)

```
<access origin="*" />
```

I also tried window.open and manual user link clicks, but all i've got is dialog to open link in external browser instead of rendering it inside same webview.
I also tried InAppBrowser extension, that works fine when i disable navigation bar but it has communication problems and doesn't work on manual link licks and window.location.href changes.

Comment: have you tried `window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/")` ?

Comment: @ArpitVasani tried and its opening link in system browser just like other methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved this issue using following rules on both ios and android:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-navigation href="sms:*" />
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />
<allow-navigation href="geo:*" />
```

If you stuck on same problem you also need to know following:

- Multiple cordova versions has different rules structure and behaviours when docs isn't always correct about current version. In my researches i found this article very useful https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md
- My main problem was "not knowing" that allow-intent overrides allow-navigation. Make sure you understand how it works

Comment: Thanks! Specially important for me was the second bullet point (allow-intent overrides allow-navigation). Remove the according allow-intent entries (eg. for http, https). If you want to cherry pick that eg. a facebook link opens externally just add: <allow-intent href="*://*.facebook.com/*" />

Comment: I get a blank page on mobile testing

Answer (score 0):

### How to load [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to Cordova WebView?

```
    <allow-navigation href="https://example.com/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />
```

#### More information:

AFAIK, by default Cordova does not allow to load external links on WebView. However, you can still show internal html pages which are stored in your project (for example index.html etc). It's a security measure.

So you need to install this plugin [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#supported-cordova-platforms) and manually whitelist the domains that your app wants to load on Cordova WebView.

If you want to allow all the links to load in WebView you can use `<allow-navigation href="*" />` But it is not recommended.

#### Relevant links:

[Official Github link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#supported-cordova-platforms)