# Redirecting Cordova webview to external site

Tags: android, html, cordova, redirect, webview

I want to build a simple app container for a website using Cordova. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017) tutorial, which seems very helpful, but wasn't able to connect the app to my website server.

I tried many Cordova's permission settings inside the `config.xml` and had a look on some Stackoverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140298/cordova-phonegap-load-external-site-in-main-cordova-webview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692098/open-a-link-in-its-own-phonegap-default-webview), but neither of those solved my problem. None of them provided the redirection I wanted.

I don't want to use the inappbrowser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was a one liner that took three hours of my life.

After creating a Cordova project from scratch, inside `config.xml` you'll find the following line:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

Simply replace `index.html` with the site you want the app to be redirected to. For example:

```
<content src="http://www.google.com/" />
```

I'm not sure if that makes the final app insecure, though, but it works. I can finally easily embed any site into a Cordova app and build an APK with it.

Comment: Would this happen to be doable at runtime??

Comment: @SeizeTheDay I didn't find a way do to it at runtime.